# Keep double quote from JavaScript array while iterating through the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have a code snippet like the following:

```
var items = ["element_1", "element_2", "element_3"];

for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    delete userFormJsonObject[i];
}
```

The `userFormJsonObject` is a Json object and I wish to delete the node from "element_1" to "element_3" which was defined in `items` array.

Here is what my JSON object looks like in Chrome debugger:

[image]

My problem is: the loop will automatically remove the double quote and I wish to preserve the double quote for my loop. I have tried to add `\` escape character into my array, such as `"\"element_1\""`. But when I passed this into the loop, it seems not working.

I wish my loop runs just like:

```
delete $scope.userProfileDataFormTrimmed["account_id"];
delete $scope.userProfileDataFormTrimmed["active_directory_flag"];
...
```

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Comment: That's a normal array; it has nothing to do with JSON.  It sounds like you actually just want to serialize it to a JSON string.

Comment: Can you show an example of `userFormJsonObject` and what you'd like it to look like after the process?

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: The variable `i` will have the values `0`, `1`, and then `2`. Did you mean `delete userFormJsonObject[items[i]]`? Regarding your updated question, the object shown doesn't have properties called `element_1`, etc. Regarding preserving the quotes, the object you've shown does *not* have quotes in its property names.

Comment: I don't see any object property keys with quotes in that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with quotes as there are no quoted property keys.

Your problem is, instead of using the iteration index `i`, you would need use `items[i]` to get the actual value at the iteration index.

You can also use the more modern `Array.prototype.forEach` method to iterate your `items` array.

```js
let userFormJsonObject = {
  "element_1": "this is element 1",
  "element_2": "this is element 2",
  "element_3": "this is element 3",
  "element_4": "this is element 4",
  "element_5": "this is element 5",
};

let items = ["element_1", "element_2", "element_3"];

items.forEach(key => delete userFormJsonObject[key]);
// or items.forEach(function(key){delete userFormJsonObject[key]})
console.log(userFormJsonObject);
```

---

The for loop version would be

```
for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    delete userFormJsonObject[items[i]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems I need to refresh my understanding with Json.

Comment: @YangXia Again, [**it's not JSON!**](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)